# C#: Is this possible? (Providing default implementation for IEquatable in sub-interface)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

I'm trying to make an interface that has an `Id` property and then implements `IEquatable` using that Id.

However, a class that implements the intermediate-interface is throwing an error that it does not implement the `IEquatable`.

I'm guessing this type of functionality simply doesn't exist, but I'm struggling to both describe what exactly this functionality *is* and to find any workarounds for the thing I want to do.

What I want to do is to allow classes to simply implement the `IntermediateInterface` and immediately be equatable to each other via the `Id` property required by that interface.

*Here's the code as text:*

```
public interface IntermediateInterface<T> : IEquatable<T>
    where T : IntermediateInterface<T>
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    public new bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return Id.Equals(other.Id);
    }
}

public class ActualType : IntermediateInterface<ActualType> {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

*Here's the Error Text*: 

`Error   CS0535  'ActualType' does not implement interface member 'IEquatable<ActualType>.Equals(ActualType)'`

*Here's a screenshot from visual studio*:

[image]

Comment: why are you making it `new`?

Comment: Because it was suggested by Visual Studio

Comment: i would create an abstract class instead of a default interface implementation here.

Comment: I generally prefer abstract classes, but I'm trying to ultimately use this type of functionality in a situation where I might need the 'ActualType' to derive from a different class

Comment: `new` was a mistake though for sure

Comment: Don't try to force mixins.

Comment: @madreflection What do you mean?

Comment: @madreflection: I'm also confused by your comment; default implementations of interface methods is a common technique for mixins in Java, which is one of the very few features found in Java that was missing from C#. I'm somewhat skeptical of the value of default-interface-style mixins in a language where extension methods already exist, but I'm not sure what you're getting at with your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: @EricLippert: I could be wrong about this, and if you're questioning it I'm probably way off base, but I was under the impression that default interface implementations was a hack at best as far as mixins are concerned. I don't know Java that well, but if that's how Java does it and it's not considered a hack, I'll withdraw the comment, as I would have no ability to defend my position at that point.

Comment: @madreflection: I don't know if I'd go so far as to say it is a "hack", but I'm still not sure what you're getting at. Languages with full-on support for mixins usually have some mechanism for adding *state* to the object that consumes the mixin, whereas languages that support, say, extension methods, default interface implementations, or traits often allow *method implementations* but not *state*; is that the distinction you're making?

Comment: @EricLippert: While I recognize that distinction, it's not where I was going with it. My concern about it is more related to what intent is conveyed. Default interface implementation was touted as a way not to break existing code when new interface members are added. It feels like mixins were somehow conflated with that purpose. Now it can be unclear if a default implementation exists for versioning purposes or mixin purposes. I suppose someone could figure that out with a little critical thinking but I feel like you shouldn't have to.

Comment: @madreflection: Got it; that's much more clear. Thanks! I don't have a whole ton of experience with the feature in Java (my experience in the JVM family is actually mostly in Scala, which supports traits as a first-class language feature) and I did not keep an eye on the design process in C# -- I have many other pressing language design problems of my own! -- but I agree with you that "potential for off-label use" is at the very least a double-edged sword. I should take a look at the C# design notes and see if the mixin-style use case is by design or by accident.

Comment: @EricLippert: I would *love* to get your take on it. Potential blog post?

Comment: @madreflection: Good idea! I am behind on my blogging but I'll add that to the queue of possible topics. I like topics where I have to learn something along the way. :)

Comment: The [spec proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods) is pretty clear on the motivations.

A way to not breaking existing code is certainly the primary reason, but it also points out that the feature allows for **traits** - which "have proven to be a powerful programming technique"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

If I have IntermediateInterface override Equals explicitly (using the IEquatable identifier) it works how I expected.

Screenshot:

[image]

Edit:

Here's some correct code (as text!):

```
public interface IntermediateInterface<T> : IEquatable<T>
    where T : IntermediateInterface<T>
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    bool IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)
    {
        return Id == other?.Id;
    }
}

public class ActualType : IntermediateInterface<ActualType> {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's calling `Equals(object)`. If `T` is a value type, it'll box `other`, and if it's  a reference type, it'll still do a reference comparison. Implementing `IEquatable<T>` this way ends up doing nothing for you that you don't already have.

Comment: @madreflection So with value types I should use `==` instead of `.Equals`?

Comment: No, you should implement the interface's `Equals(T)` with your own logic, not just delegate it to `Equals(object)`.